# Can gas fees be paid from another account when transferring tokens using Web3?

Tags: python, ethereum, binance, web3py

```
bsc = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'
        web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
        # print(web3.isConnected())
        account_1 = '0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        private_key1 = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        account_2 = '0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        balance = web3.eth.get_balance(account_1)
        human_readable = web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether')
        print("Balance : " + str(human_readable))
        if balance > 0.01:
            nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_1)
            tx = {
                'nonce': nonce,
                'to': account_2,
                'value': web3.toWei(balance, 'ether'),
                'gas': 21000,
                'gasPrice': web3.toWei(5, 'gwei')
            }
            signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key1)
            tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
            print(web3.toHex(tx_hash))
```

I am transferring with this code. However, while doing these transactions, I want to pay the transfer fee with another account. Is it possible.
Contract, approve ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am transferring with this code. However, while doing these transactions, I want to pay the transfer fee with another account. Is it possible. Contract, approve

[You can read about meta transactions and gasless transactions here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/sending-gasless-transactions).

They are not implemented on BNB Chain, so it is not possible.